# imported css not applied on react

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack-encore

I'm importing a css file in a component but the css is not applied

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "./styles.css"

function Category(props) {

    return (
        <>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="grey-thead">
                        <th>CATEGORY</th>
                        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                        <th>RESULTS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
```

and this is `styles.css`

```
.grey-thead{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

this code is on a symfony project using `encore`

Comment: Please try to use !important like this in your styles.css:  

.grey-thead{
    background-color: grey !important;
}

After that, please let me know your result.

Comment: can you show the file hierarchy ...

Comment: component and css are in the same folder , this is not the problem, even the IDE  finds the file and autocomplete it

Comment: Did you test using !important?

Comment: yes, and is not working

Comment: Are you using other css frameworks like bootstrap or tailwindCSS?

Comment: I added one answer. Please check that and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following css:

```
.grey-thead th{
    background-color: grey;
}
```